# Copying web page content in Safari to HTML

Tags: safari, web-browsing, html, text

Is there an easier way to copy and paste website content in HTML?

What I want to copy looks like this:

```
Product Information:

Length: S / M / L

Material: Polyester and Elasthane

Brand: Roxana Exclusive

Style: Basque
```

But when I paste it into my content box it looks like this:

```
Product Information
Length:
S / M / L
Material:
Polyester and Elasthane
Brand:
Roxana Exclusive
Style:
Basque
```

Then I need to edit it in an HTML editor to rearrange it.

Is there an app or plugin that will turn the text of the page into HTML so it looks right when I copy it into my content box (if that makes any sense)?

Answer (score 1):

Try View->View Source. If the web site does not use too much javascript the data you want will be visible inside HTML markup.

Comment: Iv tried that, there is to much information there to find it, if it is even there. I don't think it is the source for the particular page i think it is the whole site. Do you not no of any apps or plugins i could get? Thanks :-)

Comment: No it will be the source of that page not the whole site

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you first asked this over in the Ubuntu forum... :)

Easiest standard way is to right-click / control-click on the table or whatever, select "Inspect Element", click on a higher or lower element if necessary (say, to go from a table cell to the whole table — very useful, that ability), then right-click / control-click and "Copy as HTML".

There might be [extensions](http://extensions.apple.com) which make this easier.